# kernal panic not syncing

Tags: 13.04

There is no operating system on my HP desktop I
Have lubuntu 13.04 and when I enter try or install it gives me kernal panic-not syncing attempted to kill unit 0x00000007 under says drm kms helper panic occurred switching back to text console and nothing else I've checked ram I've tested memory not sure what else I can do

Comment: did you find solution for this??